# Google Chrome blocked redirect with window.top.location in iframe

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to redirect my website from iframe to main url, here is my code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.top.location = jQuery("link[rel=canonical]").attr("href") + "#ref=shahrekhabar";
    return false;
}, 100);
```

It works on Firefox but Google Chrome blocked this type of redirecttion.
I try with `window.top.location.href` and `window.top.location.replace` and `window.top.location.assign` but no luck.

The reason:

Some spam sites shows my site in iframe and I want to escape from them and I think redirection is good solution.

Comment: Commenting here to further ping you as I've updated my answer, really wish SO had messaging.  You should also update your question to include the fact that you're actually trying to prevent your page from being loaded by outside sites, not so much that you are just trying to change the parent frame source (which by itself is a bit silly).

Answer (score 2):

## Edit to answer the TRUE question:

A common issue with stack overflow is that users will often ask how to do something they think solves the problem they are encountering, rather than just asking us how to solve the problem.  We always appreciate hearing how you've gone about trying to solve your problem, but it's always best if we know that **and** what the root problem is.  So in your case, given your comment on my answer, the question should have been:

> Currently my website is being shown in iframes on sites that I have no control over?  I'd like to prevent them from doing this, how can I do so?  I'm currently trying to redirect my website from iframe to main url, but it won't work on Chrome.  ... Rest of question ...

Given this question, my original answer is useless as:

- You still can't and shouldn't be able to alter the URL of the parent window.
- You don't own the sites showing your page in the iframe, which means you can't register a listener to handle the postMessage or CustomEvent.

Funny enough, what you're trying to do is the exact reason why chrome doesn't let you do it hahaha.  But don't worry there is still a solution.

#### Introducing CORS!

CORS or Cross Origin Resource Sharing is the name for when a site on one domain accesses resources that aren't on the same domain.  Doesn't matter who owns either site, if the two domains are different it's CORS.  Now this is good for you because there are such things as CORS policies where you can prevent anyone from even accessing a resource on your domain if they make a CORS request.  Keep in mind this will mean you can't display your site within an iframe on another one of your sites unless they're on the same domain, but it sounds like it may be worth it for you.

In case you're curious, unlike what you're trying to do, using CORS policy is very much standard procedure for developers that don't wish for their sites to appear in iframes and is in fact used by famous sites such as facebook, google, and even good ole stackoverflow (I would know, I tried to make a way to view multiple questions at the same time via iframes a while back).  I've included an example below that shows this all to be true, alongside an example of a site that doesn't care (editpad.org).  In order to implement this on your site [check out this link](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options).

```html
<iframe src="https://www.editpad.org/"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/"> </iframe>
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53917955"> </iframe>
```

## The old answer:

So you're trying to change the location of the parent window from an iframe?  This sounds extremely dangerous and the fact that Firefox **doesn't** block it worries me.  Good job Chrome!

#### Why wouldn't you want this?

I can think of a few reasons you wouldn't want this, but the biggest is that it's just poor programming.  A page should work completely independent of whether or not it is inside an iframe, and even if the page **should** only be viewed in an iframe it still shouldn't be interacting with the parent window in such a direct way.

Possible issues that could arise if this were allowed on all platforms:

- Include an iframe in your ads and as soon as your ad is displayed, redirect the user to your site or worse, redirect them to a mirror of the current site that you're hosting to collect passwords / personal information.
- If you can mess with the windows location (arguably the most important and static thing about a web page being viewed) why can't you mess with anything?  Can you go into the parent window and adjust the DOM or do a query selection for inputs of type `password` in order to copy the values?  Or what about attaching event listeners to the parent window silently such that you can log any and all key presses.

#### How can you work around it?

Don't worry too much about the issues I brought up above, as they can all be avoided by following proper standards.  In fact, the JavaScript devs envisioned this exact problem which is why you can [post messages across windows](https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/cross-domain-iframe-parent-communication-403912fff692).  Look into this link and go from there, feel free to comment if you have any questions but it should be as simple as posting a message, detecting it on the parent window, and then changing the location as you wish.

If you need to send data from the iframe to the parent window, or your iframe isn't hosted  on the same domain, you can instead use CustomEvents (which I prefer even when my iframe is on the same domain) which allow you to attach a data object.

As for why either of these two solutions is better than directly manipulating the parent window, it's all due to the parent window needing to register a listener for the message / custom event.  If your page is not inside an iframe it'll simply post a message to itself which it won't be listening for.  If your page is inside an iframe on the page it should be on, your parent page should already have registered the proper listeners.  And there is no chance for malicious use of these features because again, I have to register a listener and I choose what is done with the event once it's caught.

Comment: Some spam sites shows my site in iframe and I want to escape from them and I think redirection is good solution.
I'll try the post that you send me, if I have more question I'll send it here.

Comment: Hmm given this extra information I think what you want to do is impossible.  As I explained, it'd be dangerous if you could control the spam sites even if they're a bunch of A-holes for using your site without permission.  Let me edit my question to include one other solution that may work for you.